# Mod alert system short coming

Tags: feature-request

Just now there is someone adding in very offensive tags, with combinations of offensive words.  They are adding them to questions.

The question add is easily dealt with, you simply edit and remove the tag.

However, there is no mechanism like on the rest of the site to flag a mod for offensive tags.

Comment: Tags with no questions (like if tag adds are reverted) are automatically deleted. not really an issue.

Answer (score 3):

If a flag does not have any questions tied to it it will be automatically removed in the near future.

The issue is someone with higher rep adding such a flag.

Comment: Side note, multiple offensive flags on a post will autodelete.

Comment: For the tag under discussion there was a suggested wiki edit (which is when I first noticed it) that we both rejected. I went with the deface / destructive rejection reason, do mods get a message when an edit is rejected for that reason? I thought you probably would so didn't bother doing anything else but would be good to know for the future if flagging another post from the same user is worthwhile to bring it to your attention.

Comment: @PeterJ We can see it in the review queue, but there's nothing that *automatically notifies us*. Flags on the original post help the most to sort this out.

Comment: I'm a little confused here.  I am referring to the TAG, one which was attached to a post (which I edited out) the other tag was not attached yet. While (once removed from a question) these tags are not visible on the main site, they still will exist in the tags for a certain amount of time.  It would be nice to be able to flag them.  There is presently no way to flag a tag at all.